# How do I write this tsc script as an npm script in package.json?

Tags: node.js, typescript, package.json, tsconfig, npm-scripts

I want to use the following script for running as an npm script:

```
tsc src/*.tsc --outDir bin
```

This command works exactly how I want when I run it in the terminal, but when I add this exact script to package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc src/*.ts --outDir bin"
  }
}
```

Then run

```
npm run compile
```

I get an error:

```
error TS6053: File 'src/*.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

I've tried adjusting options in tsconfig.json and package.json, but the terminal command is the only way I can get it to work. Here's my tsconfig.json as it stands currently:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,

    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src/*.ts", "src/*", "src/**/*", ".env"],
  "exclude": ["src/views"]
}
```

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "auth-node-with-sql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Program written to learn basic concepts of authorization and authentication using node and express",
  "main": "bin/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc src/*.ts --outDir bin",
    "lint": "npx eslint . --ext .ts",
    "start": "node bin/server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "auth-node-with-sql"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.50.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.50.0",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.16",
    "axios": "^1.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "type": "commonjs"
}
```

Folder structure is:

```
bin
node_modules
src
  /db
  /utilities
  /src.ts
.env
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Please try to run only "tsc".

Comment: Added the folder structure to post for reference. When running "tsc" it runs without error, but the files are compiled files remain unchanged

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by *"...but the files are compiled files remain unchanged..."*?

Comment: That when I inspect the js files in the bin for the changes I made in the respective ts files those changes aren't there. Does that make sense? I'm still learning the terminology so please feel free to correct me. I realized my package.json might be helpful so I've added that to the post now as well.

Comment: When I create that directory structure with a file in `src/src.ts` and do `npm run compile`, it creates a `bin` directory with `src.js` in it as expected (and updates it if I change `src/src.ts`). But that's because it's not using the `tsconfig.json`. If you do just `tsc` in the `compile` script, it will find the `tsconfig.json`, and will respect the `noEmit: true` setting -- which tells it not to emit any output files.

Comment: Oh my gosh... thank you @T.J.Crowder! That indeed fixes everything! A very silly mistake when editing the compiler configurations.

Comment: (FWIW, your `include` doesn't have to be so elaborate (TypeScript doesn't process `.env` files), just `"include": ["src/**/*.ts"]` is sufficient (a second one for `tsx` if you use JSX/TSX). Glad the `noEmit` thing solved it! Happy coding!

Comment: That is worth a lot actually! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See @TJ.Crowder's comment spotting the silly use of `"noEmit": true` in the `tsconfig.json`